# Windows Phone 8 SDK debug wont start

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have installed Windows Phone 8 SDK, openened the VS express for Windows Phone,
created New Project with simple app, pressed F5, but the emulator wont start.
Is comes up with error:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x89721800
```

I don't have any network drivers installed which should be called Windows Phone Emulator.

I have Windows 8, with built-in Administrator account and full privs.

P.s. Main reason for this I want to deploy some apps on my Nokia Lumia 800.
I have unlocked it, but when i was deploying app with deployment tool, it came up with the same error message.

P.p.s I've installed Windows Phone SDK 7 and there the emulator worked, but i can't find any way to deploy app to phone

Answer (score 1):

I blogged about this a couple of weeks ago. You can see the full details here: [Resolving windows Phone Emulator Problems](http://iserialized.com/resolving-windows-phone-emulator-errors/)

XDE cleanup, and Hyper-V is a very common reson for problems with the emulator!

Regarding deployment to phone from windows phone sdk 7, remember to change debug device from "Emulator WVGA 512 MB" (or what ever you use) to "Device", and always start Zune before your start debugging and deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you had installed Windows 8 (Single Language or Home Edition) with Windows Phone 8 SDK  you can't develop mobile applications because it doesn't support Hyper-V.

The only way to work with Windows Phone 8 is to change your OS to Windows Pro or higher.